# Excel Pivot Calculation field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to do a calculation on the below?

[image: Excel Pivot Calculation]

MOH vs Revenue is a calculated item

Sum of Fiscal Year 2018 is in Values (A)

Sum of Fiscal Year 2019 is in Values (B)

I need to calculate the difference between (A) - (B)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pivot table calculation you can do it in the table.  These are easily meant to work with distinct measures (columns) in your data.

Click in your pivot table and then click on field items sets, and choose calculated field.  Give your calculation a name.

In the formula part leave the "=" and then click on "Fiscal Year 2019", type a "-", click on "Fiscal Year 2018" and hit OK.  It should look like this in the formula bar:

```
    ='Fiscal Year 2019'- 'Fiscal Year 2018'
```

Your pivot table will now have a field with the name you chose and you can add it to your table display.  It will calculate this value for every level of your pivot table.